# Для чего нужны обобщения (generics)?

Tags: kotlin, generics

Взялся за изучение основ языка Kotlin и столкнулся с [обобщениями](https://kotlinlang.ru/docs/generics.html).

Никак не могу их "обмозговать". Не понимаю практический смысл обобщенных классов, параметров и прочего.

Может есть у кого примеры кода и ситуаций, грамотного применения обобщений?